# Passing CLI arguments through gulp-nodemon

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gulp, command-line-interface

I am using the npm package [gulp-nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon) to start my webserver.

The problem I am having is that I cannot pass CLI arguments to my server script.

I would like to write something like this:

`gulp --argument1 value1`

And the nodemon then should call `coffee server.coffee --argument1 value1`

My current nodemon task:

```
# nodemon development server
gulp.task 'nodemonServer',  () ->
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.coffee'
    ext: 'coffee'
    watch: ['server/', 'server.coffee']
    env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
  })
  .on 'crash', () ->
    notifyServerError()
```

I tried writing `script: 'server.coffee --argument1 value1'`
but I am getting a strange error:
`File not found: C:\Users\user\projectRoot\"server.coffee`

Yes, with the " in the file path. Here is the log:

```
[13:13:10] [nodemon] starting `coffee.cmd "server.coffee --argument1 value1"`
File not found: C:\Users\user\projectRoot\"server.coffee
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the argument fixed or will you supply different (or no) arguments as well?

Comment: @RahatMahbub I want to pass the arguments given to gulp as they are to the server script, `gulp --argument1 value1` results in `coffee server.coffee --argument1 value1`

Comment: If there is a limited number of arguments, `yargs` can be used to take the arg and value and conditionally pass it nodemon as nodeArgs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `args` to pass any arguments for `coffee` command. This are the agruments passed AFTER the script filename.

Use `exec` to pass any coffee options along with the `coffee` executable. These are passed BEFORE script filename.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
gulp.task('nodemonServer', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.coffee',
    exec: 'coffee -p',
    args: ['--argument','value1'],
    ext: 'coffee'
  , env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
  })
})
```

To see the actual command used by nodemon, use `DEBUG=nodemon`

`DEBUG=nodemon gulp  nodemonServer`

which logs:

```
  nodemon bus new listener: reset (0) +0ms
  nodemon bus new listener: reset (0) +6ms
  ...
[13:47:20] [nodemon] starting `coffee -p server.coffee --arguments value1`
  nodemon spawning +0ms coffee -p server.coffee --arguments value1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to some samples in the `gulp-nodemon` repository, you can use:

`nodeArgs: ['--some-arg']`

For example:

```
# nodemon development server
gulp.task 'nodemonServer',  () ->

  nodemon({
    script: 'server.coffee'
    ext: 'coffee'
    watch: ['server/', 'server.coffee']
    env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
    nodeArgs: ['--argument1', 'value1']
  })

  .on 'crash', () ->
    notifyServerError()
```

Source: [Example gulpfile from gulp-nodemon](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon/blob/master/Gulpfile.js#L41)

Comment: This sadly just works for the arguments passed to the node executable, not the server script itself..